# Can Office Scripts "Only arrow functions may be used in array method callbacks" warning be suppressed?

Tags: typescript, office365, office-scripts

Say you're writing an Office Script in Excel 365, and you want to use the following common pattern:

```
const isUpperCase = (str: string) => str.toUpperCase() === str
const texts = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getUsedRange(true).getTexts()
const rowsContainingUpperCase = texts.filter((row) => row.some(isUpperCase))
```

The last line gives a warning:

```
const rowsContainingUpperCase = texts.filter((row) => row.some(isUpperCase))
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
// Only arrow functions may be used in array method callbacks. (Office Scripts Error)
```

This looks like a linter error that can maybe be ignored, but upon attempting to run the script, it fails to run, you get this:

> See line 3, column 62: Only arrow functions may be used in array method callbacks.

Microsoft documents this in [TypeScript restrictions in Office Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/typescript-restrictions):

> Your scripts can only use arrow functions when providing callback arguments for Array methods. You cannot pass any sort of identifier or "traditional" function to these methods.

It also refers to it as a "compiler error", but it doesn't explain why this would be a compiler error, nor does it explicitly state that there's no way of suppressing it.

Is there a way to suppress the error? Or do you always have to refactor to `row.some((x) => isUpperCase(x))`?

Comment: _"You cannot pass any sort of identifier"_, so it seems that it doesn't matter whether the value it refers to was defined as an arrow or vanilla function.

Comment: That isn't a warning. It's an error, and errors can't be suppressed. Errors prevent code from compiling, and if it can't be compiled it can't be executed. The word **only** is meaningful, as is the word **cannot**, in the MS documentation.

Comment: @KenWhite In ESLint and many other linters, you can configure rules as "errors" that will indeed prevent your code from compiling, but you can also override these "errors" with a magic comment such as `// eslint-disable-next-line <rule name>`, after which your code will compile. I'm asking if there's a similar way to override this error. Basically, is it implemented as a lint rule, or is it something more fundamental about the runtime/compilation logic used by Office Scripts?

Comment: I addressed that already, when I mentioned specifically the MS documentation's use of **only** and **cannot**. The documentation says it's an error condition that cannot be worked around.

Comment: @KenWhite re-explaining your personal interpretation of everyday words such as "only" and "cannot" isn't helpful, and nowhere in the linked documentation does it say anything like "cannot be worked around". On the contrary, the intro of that article states "there are a few restrictions enforced by the Code Editor to ensure your script works consistently and as intended", which implies that those restrictions come from the editor and are meant to enforce best practices, i.e. it's reasonable to think they might be overridable.

Comment: If there was an exception to *only* and *cannot*, it would either be explained in that documentation, or a link to the exception information would have been provided. I don't see *only, except* or *cannot, unless* or any similar content.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked to is correct: passing a variable like that to an array callback is a compiler error in Office Scripts. It is not a linter warning. The workaround is to have the case evaluation logic in the callback:

```
const texts = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getUsedRange(true).getTexts();
const rowsContainingUpperCase = texts.find((row) => row.some((str: string) => str.toUpperCase() === str));
```

As to the "why" this is a compiler error, it has to do with the way Office Scripts are transpiled from synchronous to asynchronous code before being run. I'll try to get someone from the product team to comment here with more details, but TypeScript restrictions like this are effectively added to improve performance by eliminating edge cases.

Also, for what it's worth, the row finding logic in this question won't include duplicates. Not sure if that matters, but it's something I noticed.